# Question on star shaped domains

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a compact star shaped subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with *center* $x_0\in X$, that is, for every $x\in X$ the line segment $[x_0,x]=\{(1-t)x_0+tx : t\in [0,1]\}$ is contained in $X$.

Suppose $X$ has nonempty interior and that $\partial X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

*My question is:* does $X$ admit a center point in its interior?

---

I'm trying to generalize the statement "in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a compact convex set with nonempty interior is homeomorphic to the unit ball $\mathbb{D}^n$", which I proved using the fact that *we can translate the convex so that the origin belongs to its interior* and then the proof does not depend on any other point than the origin (that is a center for the convex).

Therefore, if the answer to my question is "yes", then it's true that "in $\mathbb{R}^n$, a compact star shaped set with nonempty interior and boundary homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^n$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this has only one center lying on his boundary[image: example]

Comment: Such a simple counterexample, you got it! However this set is clearly homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^2$, its just the case that my proof will not work as I expexted. I'm wondering if what I wrote in quotes in the final of my question is true or not.. Anyway, thanks a bunch!

Comment: @rldias In $\mathbb{R}^2$ any compact set bounded by a (topological) circle is homeomorphic to $D^2$ (Jordan–Schoenflies theorem).

Comment: @rldias I believe it is true because being star shaped is a strong requirement. However, if you want to construct a counterexample, you must be aware of the generalized Schoenflies theorem which says that a locally flat embedded sphere $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e. $S \approx S^{n-1}$) bounds a (topological) ball.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a counterexample. Consider the closed 1st quadrant $Q = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x,y \ge 0\}$. Let $I_x = [0,1] \times 0$, and let $I_y = 0 \times [0,1]$.

I'm going to describe a Jordan arc $J$ with endpoints $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ such that $J \cup I_x \cup I_y$ is a Jordan curve bounding a compact set $X$, hence $X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb D^2$, and $(0,0)$ is a star point for $X$, but no interior point is a star point for $X$.

The arc $J$ is the polar coordinate graph of a function
$$r = f(\theta), \quad 0 \le \theta \le \pi/2
$$
with $f(0)=f(\pi/2)=1$. There will be an infinite, strictly increasing sequence 
$$0 = \theta_0 < \theta_1 < \theta_2 < \cdots
$$
with $\lim_{i \to +\infty} \theta_i = \pi/2$, and I'll denote $a_i$ to be the point in the plane represented by polar coordinates $(\theta_i,r(\theta_i))$. The portion of $J$ with $\theta_{i-1} \le \theta \le \theta_i$ will be denoted $J_i$, and it is simply the Euclidean line segment 
$$J_i = [a_{i-1},a_i]
$$
Thus, $J$ is obtained by adding the point $(0,1)$ to the  concatenation of the closed line segments
$$J_0 J_1 J_2 \cdots
$$
As $n \to +\infty$ the segments $J_n$ will decrease in length to zero and approach $(1,0)$.

The idea is to construct the $J_n$'s so that the limit of the Euclidean slope of $J_n$ is equal to $+\infty$, but this limit is acheived in a "zig-zaggy" way that prevents any interior point of $X$ from being a center point.

Here's a few details on how to achieve this result. Consider $n \ge 1$. If $n$ is odd we require that $|a_{n-1}| < |a_n|$, and hence $J_n$ has "positive polar slope", because $r$ is increasing as a function of $\theta$ along the segment $J_n$. Also, if $n$ is even we require that $|a_{n-1}| > |a_n|$, hence $J_n$ has "negative polar slope". Finally, as $n \to +\infty$ we require that the **Euclidean** slope of $J_n$ approaches $+\infty$; hence for odd $n$ the polar slope is approaching $+\infty$ and for even $n$ the polar slope is approaching $-\infty$.

From these conditions, for any interior point $p \in Q$ one sees that for sufficiently large odd values, the point $p$ lies on the "outside" of the segment $J_n$, hence the line segment from $p$ to any point in the interior of $J_n$ does not lie in $Q$.

Comment: Well done! Now I'm wondering if the result I was trying to prove is true, since your example is still homeomorphic to $\mathbb{D}^2$.. Thank you!